# Tildes en Docstrings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python y tras realizar uno de mis primeros módulos quiero documentar el mismo pero tengo un problema, cuando pongo toda la documentación con tildes, me salen carácteres codificados.

Busqué por Google y encontré alguna referencia pero nada claro. En la primera línea del módulo añadí lo siguiente:

**# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-**

Añado un ejemplo:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""" Función encargada de emitir un sonido en forma de pitido.

Parametros opcionales:
- "duracion" : duración del sonido en milisegundos.
- "frecuencia" : frecuencia del sonido en hercios.
"""
```

Y por consola obtengo lo siguiente:

```py
EjecutarSonido(duracion=300, frecuencia=500)
Funci¾n encargada de emitir un sonido en forma de pitido.

Parametros opcionales:
- "duracion"    : duraci¾n del sonido en milisegundos.
- "frecuencia"  : frecuencia del sonido en hercios.
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

¡Muchas gracias y un saludo!

Comment: Puedes agregar un ejemplo de tu documentacion?

Comment: ¿Estás en Python 3, seguro?

Comment: Acabo de añadir un ejemplo. Y si, estoy utilizando Python 3.4.7.

Comment: ¿El fichero .py está codificado en ANSI o UTF8?

Comment: Estaba como UTF-8 sin BOM, lo cambié a UTF-8 desde el Notepad++ y sigue igual.